# "Topics" in homological algebra

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, model-categories, derived-categories

What are some nice references for some more advanced homological algebra than, say, Weibel ? (i.e. taking Weibel for granted in a sense)

Are there some that use model categories in their approach to derived stuff ?

I have no specific requirements as regards applications that would be present in the references, although I would rather have them stay at the level of applications, and not be the focus of the reference.

Comment: Not that I am sure, but I heard that the book by Gelfand and Manin has some pretty advanced stuff. Might be worth trying, but I cannot promise that it is what you are looking for.

Comment: @ThorWittich I can't say for sure, but the table of contents seems to indicate it does not go much further than Weibel + some model category theory. But I may be wrong, sometimes the table of contents can hide some things

Comment: $t$-structures ? It appears in algebraic geometry (perverse sheaves or motives) and representation theory. I don't know enough algebraic topology but it should also be related to model categories.